Fractal Subdivision for Procedural Generation
This is my first attempt at creating a thread here, thus I'm not sure how much context I need to provide you. Please leave a commend if you need additional info. With that disclaimer out of the way, let's get into the point.
I decided to tackle a Minecraft (Java 1.20) Settlement Procedural Generation as my master's thesis. Here is a link to a similar competition (Generative Design in Minecraft).
The user must define an ingame rectangle area in world coordinates (from square X=0, Y=0, Z=0 to X=100,Y=100, Z=100) as an input and the algorithm must generate a settlement there. The goal is to make a settlement that resembles human generated content. I decided to create an algorithm that focuses mostly on creating interesting city shapes and realistic building placement.
Example user input (in Minecraft chat) in a loaded world
/setbuildarea 0 0 0 200 0 200

Meaning: the build area will start from point P_0=(0,0,0) and end to the point P_1=(200, 0, 200). Minecraft convention is X=length, Y=height, Z=width. (There is syntax for getting the current player location but I will try not to bore you with semantics).
then the user runs the python script while the Minecraft is open.
For context, my current idea (after reading the book "Fractal Cities: A Geometry of Form and Function") are the following Steps:

Get (the rectangular) Build Area from user

Scan Area for points of Interest (POI). (Valleys, Mountain Peaks, Rivers/Lakes, Resources, existing player structures etc.) and Scan for Obstacles (Steep Slopes, large water body, Lava, other buildings)

Filter out Obstacles from the build area (avoid demolishing existing buildings)

a) Generate a fractal city shape (to avoid boring and too random cityscapes) with Recursive subdivision of the initial rectangular area (that must incorporate the detected POI and avoid Obstacles. b) Primary Subdivisions will assign each area into districts (Business, Residential, Recreation/Open Space,...). c) Secondary subdivisions will divide each district into house blocks. d) Tertiary subdivisions will divide each block into specific buildings (apartments, roads, etc.).

Apply an erosion algorithm to carefully flatten the area of each building to realistically place each building there. "Carefully" meaning that erosion blocks moving down the slope of the heightmap should not mess with other buildings nearby.

For each final subdivision, build each building into its committed area from a defined building library


Now here is my question:
How can I make the fractal subdivision process? I know how to generate fractals from points. But how can I generate asymmetric fractals with subdivisions and how can I subdivide an asymmetric shape into smaller asymmetric parts? I would appreciate a link to a video, book, course, etc.
I know how to generate known fractals via the Iterated Function System equations:
IFS equations for fractal generation
which must be applied on all points of the generated fractal (and which I can make asymmetric by changing the transformation length with pseudorandomness.
For example I know how to create an interesting city-looking shape from a Koch Snowflake:
Kock Snowflake
My main question is how to generate such a shape with successive subdivision of a rectangle grid, while making sure that specific POI points stay inside the perimetry of the generated fractal and that the fractal remains a single connected shape?
Here is an ideal output of a desired shape:
enter image description here
Any help will be much appreciated.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.
